# How to interpret Pearson's $r$, Spearman's $\rho$, Cramér's $\phi_{c}$ and Cramér's $V$ correctly?

Tags: interpretation, pearson-r, spearman-rho, cramers-v

Is it right that both Cramér's $\phi_{c}$ (and consequently [Cramér's $V$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V) as well) are similar to the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient), $r$, (and so, to [Spearman's $\rho$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)) in its interpretation, as it is written here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient)?

Does a Cramér's $V$ value of 0.30 indicate a stronger relationship between two variables than a Pearson correlation coefficient of 0.20?

Consequently: Can I compare the strength of the relationship between different variables? Let's say for example. The strength between income and consumer spending is stronger than the relationship between distance (in classes) and consumer spending or gender and consumer spending?

Comment: Jan, keeping tight grammar and orthographics (e.g. capitalizing proper names) keeps the quality of questions up (and you have contributed a cool question). Also: click on the edit link (lower left) to see how I added the Greek characters and links.

Comment: Any ideas out there?